# sprintf writing a blank string when used with %*.s format specifier

Tags: c, printf, format-specifiers

I have an sprintf as follows -

```
sprintf (output,"%.*s%s%s%s",length,Str1,Str2,Str3,Str4);
```

All the strings contain valid data and the length parameter as well is correct.
Yet, output remains emtpty after this sprintf.

If I replace %.*s with %s and remove the length parameter, it works perfectly fine.

Comment: It is infact %.*s that is not working. I corrected it now in the question. My bad.

Comment: Post a compete example.

Answer (score 1):

Try This

Change

```
sprintf (output,"%*.s%s%s%s",length,Str1,Str2,Str3,Str4);
```

To

```
sprintf (output,"%.*s%s%s%s",length,Str1,Str2,Str3,Str4);
                  ^^
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason why nothing is being output is because if you omit the trailing digit or star after the dot, the precision is taken to be zero. `%*.` modifies the *width* not the *precision*. Instead, you want `%.*`. Note that this only applies to the conversion specifier it is a part of. i.e:

```
char output[100];
char str1[] = "hello";
char str2[] = "there";
int length = 4;

sprintf(output, "%.*s%s", length, str1, str2);
printf("%s", output);
```

Output:

```
hellthere
```